# Angular directive that requires another directive that uses an Attribute defined controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning angular and when I was studying custom directives I got stuck in a situation that I don't know how to solve. Here are my custom direcives:

```js
/**
 * Created by Lucas on 11/06/2015.
 */
'use strict'

eventsApp

    .directive('greeting',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: "<button class='btn' ng-click='sayHello()'>Say Hello</button>",
            controller: function GreetingController($scope) {
                var greetings = ['hello'];
                $scope.sayHello = function() {
                    alert(greetings.join());
                }
                this.addGreeting = function(greeting) {
                    greetings.push(greeting);
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('finnish',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'greeting',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addGreeting('hei');
            }
        }
    })
    .directive('hindi',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'greeting',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addGreeting('नमस्ते');
            }
        }
    });
```

These directives work fine, however, if I change the `greeting` controller to receive an external controller via an attribute like this:

```js
.directive('greeting',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: "<button class='btn' ng-click='sayHello()'>Say Hello</button>",
            controller: '@',
            name: 'ctrl'
        };
    })
```

And make a reference in the HTML like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Event Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<greeting ctrl="GreetingController">
    <div finnish hindi></div>
</greeting>

<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/GreetingController.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/greeting.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
   </html>
```

The other directives stop working, angular logs the following error:

**Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'greeting', required by directive 'hindi', can't be found!**

I imagine that there is a way to fix this, but since I'm new in Angular I'm quite a bit lost.

Comment: I made a plunkr here http://embed.plnkr.co/18ExMUHD1nTuhYEs6fMs/preview and its working for me. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr. I guess that user3906922 answered my question. I updated the question in case you want to see the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the controller as an attribute, the attribute name needs to be the name of the directive:

```
<greeting greeting="GreetingController" finnish="" hindi=""></greeting>
```

See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/VD4HDx7skNoit5xVS8gu?p=preview) plunker

Comment: Thanks, That was exactly what I needed. I just didn't up vote because I don't have reputation to do so.